# Find the next lowest value than the last record in a MYSQL table in a real time DB

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, min

I have a simple table that tracks a video file and a program_id number like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      id             |    filename      |  program_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |   vid1.mp4       |     1001         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |   vid2.mp4       |     1010         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |   vid3.mp4       |     1005         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

What i'd like to do is pull the lowest program ID, then go and pull the next LOWEST program ID from the database. The program_id isnt linear because I insert and delete videos in between them so the looping code can pull the next lowest video in case a new one is added. So on the first pass i would want expect 1001, next pass 1005 then next pass 1010.

Right now I successfully just have this where i can pull the lowest program_id in python:

```
while true:
    sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE program_id =  ( SELECT MIN(program_id)  FROM video)"
    cnx.execute (sql)
    result = cnx.fetchall()
    for qq in result:
        id = qq[0]
        filename = qq[1]
        program_id = qq[3]

  playVideo(filename)
```

is there a way to use loop around and do another query using the last programn_id and select the next lowest from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe Limit and offset for getting the next video

> ```
> CREATE TABLE videos  (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `filename` VARCHAR(8),
>   `program_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO videos 
>   (`id`, `filename`, `program_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'vid1.mp4', '1001'),
>   ('2', 'vid2.mp4', '1010'),
>   ('3', 'vid3.mp4', '1005');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM videos  ORDER BY program_id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | filename | program_id
> -: | :------- | ---------:
>  1 | vid1.mp4 |       1001
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM videos  ORDER BY program_id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | filename | program_id
> -: | :------- | ---------:
>  3 | vid3.mp4 |       1005
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM videos  ORDER BY program_id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | filename | program_id
> -: | :------- | ---------:
>  2 | vid2.mp4 |       1010
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6bf3caaf47842d8a8e7f3661e2c36f7c)*

```
i = 0
while true:
    sql = "SELECT * FROM videos  ORDER BY program_id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET "+str(i);
    cnx.execute (sql)
    result = cnx.fetchall()
    for qq in result:
        id = qq[0]
        filename = qq[1]
        program_id = qq[3]
    i = i +1
    playVideo(filename)
```

But as you are only getting one row at all you don't need the for loop.

Also you need a break point for leaving the While loop for example when there are no rows anymore.

Comment: this worked really well avoiding the max/mix use but still allowing it to be dynamically updated! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the point for running a separate query to get each row here.

You could simply run a single query that gives you the videos sorted by increasing `program_id`, and then loop over *the results* of the query:

```
while true:
    sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY program_id"
    cnx.execute (sql)
    result = cnx.fetchall()
    for qq in result:       -- fetch each video, ordered by "programm_id"
        id = qq[0]
        filename = qq[1]
        program_id = qq[3]
        playVideo(filename) -- play this video
```